# Circuit Diagram to Breadboard

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, breadboard

[image]

I'm really confused on how to implement this circuit diagram on a breadboard. The short wire indicated with v1 is the confusing part. I tried to make it on a breadboard but I can't seem to get it. Any hints?

[image]

**EDIT:** This is my attempt at building the circuit. But I'm not sure if it's right and I can't test it because I do not have a multimeter. Any comments/tips? I don't have any 100k resistors, so I just used two random ones, but everything is labelled.

Comment: What is it about the V1 node which confuses you?

Comment: I don't understand how to implement it on a breadboard? Would I , in essence just build two smaller loops and attach them with a wire?

Comment: Oh, that's pretty far from the correct circuit, also your "100K" resistors are 100 ohms and 220 ohms. Where is the ground wire?

Comment: I assume the black wire is connected to the battery negative terminal.  Your breadboard shows it connected to just one 100K resistor - that's not what the schematic shows.  It would be much easier to discuss problems with your layout if you put reference designators (R1, R2...) on the components in the schematic, and on the correponding parts on the breadboard.  That may help you to see the faults in the breadboard layout.

Comment: Your first 10k does not connect to the same pin row as the following resistors, there is no connection to them. At least it looks that way in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

That's a **schematic** diagram, not a wiring diagram so position of components and length of "wires" on the diagram are (usually) not significant. The purpose of the diagram is to convey the working or operation of the circuit rather than show you how to lay it out.

There are four resistors connected at V1. The electrical connections should be very low resistance (< 1 Ω) in most assembly methods and it won't matter whether they're all soldered to one pin, neatly soldered into a PCB with tracks connecting the common points together, clamped in individual screw terminals with a connecting bar, etc.    The important point is that they are all connected and that all four components share the same V1 potential.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about a solderless breadboard, they generally have strips of five holes in a row that are connected together.

You stick one end of four resistors into the same strip and you can also put a wire into there if you need to measure the voltage (ignore the little thread off my shirt).

[image]

You could also use two (or more) strips and connect them with a wire or wires. The topology is the same in any case- which takes a little getting used to when you are learning.